# Determine which of the following spaces are separable

Tags: general-topology

A topological space $(X,\tau)$ is said to be seperable if it has a  dense subset which is countable.Determine which of the following spaces are seperable.

(i) the set $\mathbb{R}$ with the usual topology:

$\mathbb{Q} \subset \mathbb{R}$ is a dense subset and is countable,So $\mathbb{R}$ is seperable.

(ii)a countable set with discrete topology :

All proper subset of $X$ will be close ,so its closure is itself.So they aren't dense.$X \in \tau$ So $X$ is open and $\phi \in \tau$ so $X$ is close also.$X$ is closed,so its closure is $X$ itself.So is dense and $X$ is countable.So $(X,\tau)$ is seperable.

(iii)a countable set with the finite closed topology:

Similarly here $X$ is dense and being countable,the topological space is seperable.

(iv)$(X,\tau)$ where $X$ is finite.

Similarly here $X$ is dense in itself and being finite is countable.So Topological space is seperable.

(v)$(X,\tau)$ where $\tau$ is finite.

Taking $\tau$ as indiscrete topology.So only open and close sets are $X$ and $\phi$. $X$ is dense but unless it is countable we cannot say $\tau$  is seperable.

(vi)a uncountable set with the discrete topology.

only dense set is $X$ but $X$ is not countable so Topology is not seperable.

(vii)an uncountable set with the finite closed topology

Here $X$ is dense set but not countable.I am unable to conclude whether any countable subset of $X$ can be dense or not?

Please check i believe my arguments are correct for first six topology.And give me a hint for seventh one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For v : pick one element from each $O \in \tau\setminus\{\emptyset\}$ and convince yourself all such points together are dense.

So in fact any space where $\tau$ is at most countable is separable.

(vii): any countably infinite subset cannot be closed (it's not finite) so the only closed superset is $X$ and so *any* countably infinite subset (which exists) is dense.

The other arguments are OK.

Answer (score 1):

Your (i-iv),(vi) seem fine to me.

For (v), why do you assume $\tau$ is indiscrete? Even in that case, what about some intermediate countable set $A \subsetneq X$?

For both questions (v) and (vii), I offer one **HINT:** can you create a set which is not a subset of any closed set?

Comment: $X$ is always both open and close.So how can i create a set which is not a subset of this closed set $X$?I am not getting what you want to say please elaborate?

Comment: @mathstudent The closure of a set $A \subset X$ is the intersection of all closed sets $C \supseteq A$. So if you can find a set $A$ where the only closed $C$ that is a superset of $A$ is $X$, then you have a dense set.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know that I'm correct about it....for example we know that in indiscrete top space any subset with more than two points have every point as a limit point....so if we just take say R with indiscrete top space and take just any finite set then it'll dense in R .....seems to b separable.

Sorry if I'm incorrect... I'm newby to topology.

Comment: Since this is more of a speculation than actually an answer so this would better fit as a comment. You'll be able to leave comments under the posts of other users once you gain sufficient reputation.